# JSTree: Dynamically adding Node-Array as children to a Node

Tags: jstree

I am using XML data plugin to load initial JSTree. Is there a way to add a whole different tree as children from XML via an Ajax call to one of the Child-Nodes?

The create_node allows to add one node at a time.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ajax call` to 'add' data to a node. Please read about [ajax config section](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/xml_data)

- Make its status `close` so the ajax will be called.
- Then on the server side you return as much data as you want.